# Looping Through Firebase Datasnapshot and storing values in an array

Tags: android, arrays, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was working on a simple Android magazine app and I would like to iterate through Firebase DataSnapshot to retrieve stored information about magazines and save them in different arrays.[I used this step by step instructions to retrieve data from Firebase database](https://www-staging.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html).I tried looking for other questions but they didn't help.

```
 DatabaseReference ref;
        ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("magazines");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                magazineNameSize(5);
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Magazine magazine = snapshot.getValue(Magazine.class);
                    dateOfIssue[i] =magazine.getDateOfIssue();
                    magazineCover[i]=magazine.getImageUri();
                    magazineName[i]=magazine.getMagazineName();
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> dateOfIssue = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> magazineCover = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> magazineName = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference ref;
        ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("magazines");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Magazine magazine = snapshot.getValue(Magazine.class);
                dateOfIssue.add(magazine.getDateOfIssue());
                magazineCover.add(magazine.getImageUri());
                magazineName.add(magazine.getMagazineName());
                //value are store in three different arraylist
            }
        }
```

Comment: I exactly did what you suggested and copied the array list to arrays. My current problem is, I can't access those arrays from another class.

Answer (score 0):

To store those values in `dateOfIssue, magazineCover and magazineName` arrays, you need to declare those arrays in the `onDataChange()` method otherwise you'll get `null` outside this method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just did and it didn't make a difference. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You need also to use those arrays inside that method. Did you do this?

Comment: Yap, I did that too.And it works just fine. Thanks .

Comment: Happy to hear that it works. So if you consider that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks